# Hand tracing a pseudo code

Tags: pseudocode

I have this pseudo code that I need to hand trace:

```
begin
  count <- 1
  while count < 11
    t <- (count ^ 2) - 1
    output t
    count <- count + 1
  endwhile 
end
```

I am unsure what `<-` means and I don't really understand what to do with the `t`. I also keep getting 1,1,1, etc. every time I go through. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: <- means "gets", i.e., the variable is assigned the value on the RHS of the operator

Comment: you said it is pseudo code, how do you calculate (count^2)? power(count, 2)? 1^2 is one. 2^2 is four. 3^2 is nine. ? And what about count <-- count + 1. "<--" is used purposely?

Comment: You "need" to do this, but you have had no explanation or training for how the pseudo code is written?

Answer (score 1):

First off the operator `<-` means "gets", as in an assignment. So:

```
count <- count + 1
```

Means to set the variable `count` to the value `count + 1`.

Second the program will output the first 10 values of x<sup>2</sup>-1, so:

```
t <- count^2 - 1
```

will evaluate to:

```
0, 3, 8, 15, 24, 35, 48, 63, 80, 99
```

for the values of `count`

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

respectively.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code for it in C++, hope it helps:

```
int count = 1; // count <- 1
 int t;
 while ( count < 11 ){ // while count < 11
    t = count * count - 1; // t <- (count ^ 2) - 1
    std::cout<<t<<std::endl;  //  output t
    count ++; // count <- count + 1
} //  endwhile
```

and as said in the previous answer:
count takes the values: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10`

and t will take the values: `0, 3, 8, 15, 24, 35, 48, 63, 80, 99`